# computing permanent of a 0-1 rectangular matrix

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, matrices

I need to compute the [permanent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) of a 10*100 matrix. All the entries are either 0 or 1.

All I know is that I can compute the permanent of all 10*10 submatrices and then sum it to get the desired answer. But this involves 100C10=10^13 operations which is too much in my case.

Is there a better algorithm for this task?

Comment: Are you sure it is 10*100 matrix? What is the meaning of "100C10". I do not know this notation. Do you have any interesting recurrence relation on computing permanents?

Comment: 100C10= 100!/(10!*90!)....for a n*n matrix I can compute the permanent in O(2^n*n^2) time...but problem here is it is a rectangular matrix

Comment: Thanks for the combination notation, I knew 2 others, not this one (good idea, actually). Your wikipedia link says a lot of things about permanent. Did you read it? It say for example that the matrix is square. It also says other things about complexity. Anything special about the elements of your matrics? ... are they simply real numbers?

Comment: yes, I read it actually....only specialty is its a 0-1 matrix...

Comment: I was expecting your answer. And you did not even bother give that
information in your question, thus possibly wasting the time of people
who might try to answer. To be clear: I did not know permanents even
existed. But I read very cursorily the wikipedia article. Your
question still states it is a 10*100 matrix, which does not seem very
square to me. Where does your question come from? Are you sure your
matrix does not have other properties that you forgot to mention?

Comment: sorry about that, I will include it in the question...actually I was trying to figure out the number of transversals given a collection of sets which brought me here.

Comment: Well, I hope I was not being rude ... it is just that so many questions omit relevant information. It seems that permanents are tough to compute. Are you sure you are going in the right direction? (BTW, I saw they extend permanents to rectangular matrices ... it has escaped me). They propose various computation formulae ... but nothing very optimistic.

Comment: As I told you the actual problem statement is to find the number of transversals (system of distinct representatives) given 10 sets and each of the set can be {1,2,...,100} in worst case....As of now I don't know in which other way to go to solve this problem...

Comment: I don't know a better algorithm, but I do know that calculating the permanent of a 0-1 matrix is a classic #P-complete problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_is_sharp-P-complete)... so you may need to look into numerical/approximation methods for problems in #P.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions a fast algorithm due to Ryser, which runs in exponential rather than factorial time, and is the assymptotically fastest algorithm known. Have you checked it?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the permanent of a rectangular matrix? This is not a standard notion.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent#Permanents_of_rectangular_matrices